# Is there any possibility to use pretty url for php without .htaccess

Tags: php, url, web-config, mapping, windows-hosting

I have a site which use wired URL structure like:

> http://www.example.com/course-detail.php?CourseId=NzI=&SubCategoryId=MQ==&DivisionId=MQ==

I would like to see the structure like:

> http://www.example.com/course-details/course-name/

Note: The site is hosted on `Windows` server so `.htaccess` won't work to map URL.

Is there any other possibility to change this URL structure?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you should retag question to `web.config` and remove `htaccess` tag than.

Comment: Thanks Mate done with editing

Answer (score 1):

Your site is hosted on windows server right? so .htaccsess will not work, because it work with Apache server, on windows server you have to use IIS server, so you need web.config.

i am already doing URL rewrite on windows server with core PHP,

try this web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^.*$" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile"  />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory"  />
      </conditions>
      <action type="None" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^.*$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Sorry but not helping much there is no effect of creating the web.config file

Comment: where did you put on your web.config?? and please check is  there another web.config outside your project folder? having two web.config effect on second web.config

Comment: It's in my root directory of the site and there is no other web.config file outside.

Answer (score -1):

you must open the authority of httpd.conf of apache,[find this,and change 'None' to 'All',all in httpd.conf must be changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okrWn.png),then restart the wampserver,and the .htaccess would be work

Comment: The site is already hosted and I don't have permission to open apache httpd.conf. any other solution would you like to suggest?